# C# 7.2 In Keyword Performance

Tags: c#, performance, benchmarking

I am trying to test how much performant (Or not) the "in" keyword added to C# is. The in keyword should be able to pass a readonly reference to a value type into a method, instead of first copying the value then passing it in.

By bypassing this copy, in should be faster, but in my tests it doesn't seem any faster at all.

I am using BenchMarkDotNet to benchmark my code. The code looks like :

```
public struct Input
{
    public decimal Number1 { get; set; }
    public decimal Number2 { get; set; }
}

public class InBenchmarking
{
    const int loops = 50000000;
    Input inputInstance;

    public InBenchmarking()
    {
        inputInstance = new Input
        {
        };
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public decimal DoSomethingRefLoop()
    {
        decimal result = 0M;
        for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
        {
            result = DoSomethingRef(ref inputInstance);
        }
        return result;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public decimal DoSomethingInLoop()
    {
        decimal result = 0M;
        for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
        {
            result = DoSomethingIn(inputInstance);
        }
        return result;
    }


    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public decimal DoSomethingLoop()
    {
        decimal result = 0M;
        for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
        {
            result = DoSomething(inputInstance);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public decimal DoSomething(Input input)
    {
        return input.Number1;
    }

    public decimal DoSomethingIn(in Input input)
    {
        return input.Number1;
    }

    public decimal DoSomethingRef(ref Input input)
    {
        return input.Number1;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm including a loop to use the "ref" keyword which also passes by reference, but is not readonly. This does seem to be faster.

The results of this test are :

```
             Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Scaled | ScaledSD |
------------------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|-------:|---------:|
 DoSomethingRefLoop | 20.15 ms | 0.3967 ms | 0.6058 ms |   0.41 |     0.03 |
  DoSomethingInLoop | 48.88 ms | 0.9756 ms | 2.5529 ms |   0.98 |     0.08 |
    DoSomethingLoop | 49.84 ms | 1.0872 ms | 3.1367 ms |   1.00 |     0.00 |
```

So using "in" doesn't seem to be faster at all. I feel like it's possible that something is being optimized in a way I don't anticipate and that's accounting for the performance difference. I have tried increasing the size of the struct up to 16 decimal fields, but again, it didn't make a difference between in and by value.

How can I structure my benchmark test to truly see the difference between in, ref, and passing by value?

Comment: If the method call is small enough to inline, there shouldn't be any difference.  Your benchmark doesn't do anything with the return value anyway, a smarter optimizer (such as found in C++ compilers) would be removing both loop and test code.

Comment: Hi there, the BenchmarkDotNet library will use the return value so that it isn't optimized out. So I am using the return value all the way from the DoSomething upwards. Although you are right the loop could be removed. Although then that wouldn't explain why "ref" is so much faster.

Comment: You probably should be using local variables in your test loops instead of using fields. http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/benchmark.html

Comment: If the structure is small it ought to be just as fast (or faster) to "copy it". Try with a ridiculously inflated struct type (eg. tens of hundreds of bytes). This may also tease out any benchmark anomalies or find performance change-over characteristics.

Comment: Pretty sure this falls into the category of unnecessary pre-optimization.

Comment: Also, try a much bigger struct, with more fields.

Comment: It's not pre-optimization. It's just me trying to understand how the in keyword works, that's all :)

Comment: I get that. In order to get a meaningful benchmark you're going to need to try a much bigger struct. As an example, a Matrix4 has way more fields and I know from experience it's way more performant to pass it by ref.

Comment: Remember that when you use reference (in / ref) you are copying the address instead of the value. There is no reason to expect a performance improvement if the size of your struct is the same as the size of a memory address. (Any performance differences in such cases is most likely from bad testing, jit inlining, etc.) Copying 64 bits of data is still copying 64 bits - cpu doesn't care if its a memory address or your credit card saldo. However the fact that something is readonly can affect optimizations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue is that you're using a non-`readonly` struct, so the compiler is creating a defensive copy of the input argument within the `DoSomethingIn` method.

This happens because you're using the getter method of the `Number1` property, and the compiler isn't sure whether the struct state will change because of that (and since the argument is passed as a readonly reference, that wouldn't be valid).

If you edit your struct like this:

```
public readonly struct Input
{
    public decimal Number1 { get; }
    public decimal Number2 { get; }
}
```

and run the benchmark again, you'll get the same performance with the `in` method as with the `ref` method, as was your original assumption.

**NOTE:** the `readonly struct` modifier isn't mandatory, you can solve this problem by exposing the fields directly as well, like this:

```
public struct Input
{
    public decimal Number1;
    public decimal Number2;
}
```

The point is that, as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types), that:

> The compiler cannot know if any member method modifies the state of the struct. To ensure that the object is not modified, the compiler creates a copy and calls member references using that copy. Any modifications are to that defensive copy.

**EDIT #2:** to further clarify why the `readonly struct` modifier would be needed (as again, `in` is the same as `ref readonly`), here's another paragraph from the docs:

> [...] Other times, you may want to create an immutable struct. Then you can always pass by readonly reference. *That practice removes the defensive copies that take place when you access methods of a struct used as an in parameter*.

Comment: Hmm. This does work, but I'm trying to understand it better. In the official MS documentation for In (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types), they have example code that should be "faster" using the in keyword. The struct they use as an example is Point3D (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.point3d(v=vs.110).aspx), which is not readonly.

Comment: I've added a note to my answer with a better explanation of what's going on, a copy is made by the compiler whenever you're calling a method on a variable passed as `ref readonly` (the getter counts too, of course).
That's why both adding `readonly struct` and replacing the property with a field work.
In fact, at the bottom of the docs they describe a `ReadonlyPoint3D` struct that avoids the creation of these defensive copies.

Comment: That makes no sense.  The whole point of `in` is that _"[you are passing the parameter by reference and the called method does not modify the value passed to it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types)"_.  What's the point of a unnessary `readonly`.  Also, your last paragraph has nothing to do with `in` it is for [ref readonly returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types)

Comment: Hey @MickyD I kind of agree with you. But then.. I did some tests and it does seem to be right. for example take this Gist : https://gist.github.com/mindingdata/f1cc1c32c99ec1068ef51071c97d21c3 What will the output be? The answer is 1, even though inside your method you "set" it to 5. It seems that rather than work out every possible way the "readonly" might be violated, it just clones.

Comment: @MickyD You're confusing the called method not modifying the passed reference (ie. Not reassigning on that address) with the referenced struct itself not being modified, which is another desired aspect. The defensive copy is made because while the compiler can prevent you from reassigning the variable, it can't be sure whether a method called upon that variable will change its state (that's why it isn't needed if the struct is readonly). Also, `in` is basically an alias for `ref readonly`, they're the same.

Comment: @MindingData Of course the result should be `1`.  That's the whole point of **value types**, whether they are `in` or not.  Just because now they are being passed with something that looks like an object reference doesn't change the rules otherwise kittens would be dying everywhere

Comment: @Sergio0694 Hmm I don't think you understand the problem.  MindingData does. Check out his last comment and **Gist**.  That exactly backs up my point

Comment: @MickyD So in my example, because a struct is a value type, the result will always be 1? How about if we pass by ref? Will it be 1 then? No, it will be 5 because it's pointing to the same location in memory. If you disagree feel free to throw up some code here, or give another answer why the benchmark is the same as by value.

Comment: @MindingData Try it and see.  Anyway, thats a new question

Comment: @MickyD I get what you mean, I looked at the gist and I do agree the result would be 1. And you're right saying that the result there should always be 1, as you said, regardless of `in`. I think the point of having `in` is that if you just read values from the passed argument, without modifying it, you'd save a copy of the struct when passing the argument. I mean, according to the tests on the original benchmark for this question, it should be like this (I could be wrong though)

Comment: @MickyD I've edited my answer and added another extract of the docs, explaining why the defensive copy is made when passing the parameter with the `in` modifier, and why using the `readonly struct` construct solves the issue, I hope this answers your original question in your first comment.

Comment: @Sergio0694: To test whether the input is aliased or copied, best thing to do is pass in a delegate that *does* change the original variable (since the caller's view is not readonly this is allowed), call that delegate inside the function, and test whether the new value is visible through the `in` argument.

Comment: Or for that matter, simply pass the same variable as both an `in` argument and a `ref` argument, and see whether changes to the latter are visible to the former.